# How do I utter dynamic message with hyperlink attached in Rasa X?

Tags: python, hyperlink, custom-action, rasa, rasa-x

How do I utter a message, displaying results based on a datasheet, and attach a hyperlink within the text? 
Example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
    num = phone_format(str(sheet["" + chr(ord(requested_info_column)+1) + "{}".format(row)].value))
    dispatcher.utter_message(text="The " + column_names[requested_info_column] 
       + " for the " + str(sheet["B{}".format(row)].value) + " project is "
       + str(sheet["" + str(requested_info_column) + "{}".format(row)].value)
       + " and can be reached at " + num)
```

formatting method:

```
def phone_format(n):
   formatNum = '({}){}-{}'.format(n[0:3], n[3:6], n[6:])
   hypNum = '<a href="tel:%s">%s</a>' % (n, formatNum)
   return  hypNum
```

The issue I am having is that Rasa X displays the string, with the correct data, but the hyperlink is not attached to the phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying links in the front end is different for different platforms. Rasa X uses Markdown Format to display the links.

So, instead of the normal anchor tag, you need to use Markdown link format for display.

Change

```
hypNum = '<a href="tel:%s">%s</a>' % (n, formatNum)
```

to this

```
hypNum = '[%s](tel:%s)' % (formatNum,n)
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Awesome, this worked. I do not have enough points to upvote the answer, so I have to just write comments until then. Thank you very much!